# Why do I only need the name of the module in front of module functions sometimes in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, import

Recently, I've been doing a lot of coding in python and found something interesting. When doing `pd.read_csv...` I need to have `pd` in print of the function.

But, when I'm doing something like `df.to_csv...`, I don't need to put `pd` in front of the function.

I think it could have to do with pandas itself being a class potentially but I'm not sure.

I've noticed this for other libraries aswell. For example, when using `openCV`, there are some times when I need to put `cv2.` before calling a function and other times where I can just put the function without denoting which module it is from.

I've tried researching this but haven't found a very good answer.

Comment: functions related to dataframe itself are method understand that class while more general method which can be applied to dataframe or collections are under the module itself , for df.to_csv its makes more sence to convert dataframe itself into csv then do a pd.to_csv(df) and then pass df inside that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've omitted some things here that make it difficult to see the reason.

First, let's start by using the built-in [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function to see what we actually get when import pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

print(dir(pd))

#['BooleanDtype', 'Categorical', 'CategoricalDtype', 'CategoricalIndex',
# 'DataFrame', 'DateOffset', 'DatetimeIndex', 'DatetimeTZDtype', 'ExcelFile',
# 'ExcelWriter', 'Flags', 'Float32Dtype', 'Float64Dtype', 'Float64Index',
# 'Grouper', 'HDFStore', 'Index', 'IndexSlice', 'Int16Dtype', 'Int32Dtype',
# 'Int64Dtype', 'Int64Index', 'Int8Dtype', 'Interval', 'IntervalDtype',
# 'IntervalIndex', 'MultiIndex', 'NA', 'NaT', 'NamedAgg', 'Period', 'PeriodDtype',
# 'PeriodIndex', 'RangeIndex', 'Series', 'SparseDtype', 'StringDtype', 'Timedelta',
# 'TimedeltaIndex', 'Timestamp', 'UInt16Dtype', 'UInt32Dtype', 'UInt64Dtype',
# 'UInt64Index', 'UInt8Dtype', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__',
# '__docformat__', '__file__', '__getattr__', '__git_version__', '__loader__',
# '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_config',
# '_hashtable', '_is_numpy_dev', '_lib', '_libs', '_np_version_under1p17',
# '_np_version_under1p18', '_testing', '_tslib', '_typing', '_version', 'api',
# 'array', 'arrays', 'bdate_range', 'compat', 'concat', 'core', 'crosstab', 'cut',
# 'date_range', 'describe_option', 'errors', 'eval', 'factorize', 'get_dummies',
# 'get_option', 'infer_freq', 'interval_range', 'io', 'isna', 'isnull',
# 'json_normalize', 'lreshape', 'melt', 'merge', 'merge_asof', 'merge_ordered',
# 'notna', 'notnull', 'offsets', 'option_context', 'options', 'pandas',
# 'period_range', 'pivot', 'pivot_table', 'plotting', 'qcut', 'read_clipboard',
# 'read_csv', 'read_excel', 'read_feather', 'read_fwf', 'read_gbq', 'read_hdf',
# 'read_html', 'read_json', 'read_orc', 'read_parquet', 'read_pickle', 'read_sas',
# 'read_spss', 'read_sql', 'read_sql_query', 'read_sql_table', 'read_stata',
# 'read_table', 'reset_option', 'set_eng_float_format', 'set_option',
# 'show_versions', 'test', 'testing', 'timedelta_range', 'to_datetime',
# 'to_numeric', 'to_pickle', 'to_timedelta', 'tseries', 'unique', 'util', 
# 'value_counts', 'wide_to_long']
```

I want to point out two specific things that were imported `DataFrame` and `read_csv`, which you mentioned in your question.

Now, if you try to use either of these things directly (i.e **without** the `pd` prefix), the compiler will throw a `NameError`:

```
df = DataFrame(data=[1,2,3]) # NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined
x  = read_csv("my_file.csv") # NameError: name 'read_csv'  is not defined
```

When you directly do `import pandas as pd`, it keeps all the newly imported pandas functions and objects in a sort of box, which you have to refer to explicitly or else the compiler will not know what function you're referring to. This is done intentionally, since there may be namespace clashes between two modules. Take the `where` function for example - both `numpy` and `pandas` have a `where` function - if you just call `where()`, how will the compiler know which one you're referring to?

This can be avoided by using the `*` operator, like so:

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import *

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y = np.where((x%2==0), x, -1)  # you MUST use np prefix here to refer to the numpy 
                               # "box" of imported functions.
z = x.where(x > 1, -2)         # no prefix needed, since * operator was used
```

Note that you can only use `*` on one module that you import - you must use a regular import for the rest.

The last thing I want to address is the fact that no prefix is needed when you run `df.to_csv(...)`. This is because `df` is *not* something you imported from pandas directly - instead, you initialized `df` beforehand like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[1,2,3])
df.to_csv(...)
```

No prefix is needed for your function call here because `df` is something *you* created! It is a variable whose value has been initialized to a `pd.DataFrame` object, which can access its internal class method `to_csv` when you call it. It's almost like an alias for the `DataFrame` object.

To illustrate this point, you could even do something silly like this:

```
import pandas as pd

alias_func = pd.read_csv
z = alias_func("my_file.csv")
```

In short, you only need to use the module prefix when you're actually calling a function imported from a module that was imported without the `*` operator. You do not need to put the prefix when using variables/objects you initialize to `pandas` functions or objects, because you have already told the compiler which module's "box" you're referring to, and your new variable just acts as an alias.

Comment: So the extension of this is that it can be applied to python as a programming language as well. For example, you don't have to do ```python.print...``` because, python has been automatically imported in full. I know this is a weird thing to take from your answer but is there ever a case where you would need to put a keyword in front of a python function in order to let the interpreter know that it is a python function? Thanks for the answer, it was great :)

Comment: @victor__von_doom I have another question. What would happen if for example pandas and numpy both had a ```to_csv``` function? How would the python interpreter know which function to run? I assume that if one of the libraries was imported with the ```*``` that would solve the problem, but if both where imported normally, would python throw an error?

Comment: Hi @george.adams1 - per your first question no, there is no situation where you need to put the prefix ```python``` before a function - I'm pretty sure that would raise an error, actually. All python functions are imported by default.

Comment: And per your 2nd question, the python interpreter would first check if your code called a functions called ```to_csv```, then it would check if any modules imported with ```*``` defined a functionscalled ```to_csv```, then it would check if any built-in python functions exist with the name ```to_csv```, and if it finds none of the above, it would not even check pandas and numpy since you did not put the prefix - it would raise a ```NameError``` and exit. If you want pandas', write ```pd.to_csv```. If you want numpy's, write ```np.to_csv```, or use ```*``` for one of them. No other options.